# Can't dump JSON file, keep getting Type Error

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

so I have a function for my object account that once it creates itself it logs itself to a file but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting the error, TypeError: Object of type 'getset_descriptor' is not JSON serializable. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
import os
import json
import datetime

clear = lambda: os.system("cls")
now = datetime.date
temp = 1
temp_intger = None

class Account:
    def __init__(self , account_number , account_balance , account_creation , account_firstname , account_lastname):
        self.acc_number = account_number
        self.acc_balance = account_balance
        self.acc_creation = account_creation
        self.acc_firstname = account_firstname
        self.acc_lastname = account_lastname

def account_creation():
    acc = {}
    acc["account_firstname"] = input("Please enter the first name of the account")
    acc["account_lastname"] = input("Please enter the last name of the account")
    acc["account_balance"] = float(input("Please enter the balance of the account"))
    acc["account_creation"] = now.day
    while True:
        temp = input("Please enter a 4 pin number for your account!")
        if ((os.path.isfile("%s.json" %(temp))) == True):
            continue
        else:
            break
    with open("%s.json" % (temp) , "w") as fp:
        json.dump(acc,fp)

    print ("Done!")

account_creation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeError: Object of type 'getset_descriptor' is not JSON serializable is due to you date(now = datetime.date,now.day())
your json can't serialize your date object to overcome this you need to modify to your date to string

```
now = str(datetime.date)
```

and `acc["account_creation"] = str(now.day)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your trouble is on line 6: `now = datetime.date`

It looks like you're trying to create a datetime object with the current time, but that's not what you're doing with that line.

I believe you want `now = datetime.datetime.now()` there instead.